# How to identify one syllable words and two-syllable words?

Tags: grammar

One syllable words like cheap, fast, large etc and two syllable words like lucky, early etc. I want to know how to identify these word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the kind of weird version I learned as a kid. Put your hand just under your chin, and say the word. Every time there is a syllable, your chin should touch your hand.

You can also check out this page by wikihow: https://www.wikihow.com/Divide-Words-Into-Syllables

Comment: That's really a weird way to identify. But it works. So if my chin touch my hand then it means that word is one syllable right. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @AmrendraNath Yes, that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Some dictionaries (like [Wordsmyth](https://www.wordsmyth.net/?level=3&ent=early) and [American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=lucky)) include syllable information in their listings. Small dots are used to tell you not just how many syllables are in a word, but where those syllable breaks are:

[image]